# Concept between Split Code webpack

Tags: webpack

In documentation webpack : https://webpack.js.org/how-to/split-code/

There are mainly two kind of code-splits that need to be accomplished with webpack:

1. On demand code-splitting
2. Resource splitting for cacheing and parallel loads

So, the question is when we use the first choice or second choice?